# Spring Traverson and OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring, hateoas, oauth2resttemplate

I have an `OAuth2RestTemplate` to handle the communication with a REST-API and just tried to use this in combination with a `Traverson`, like so:

```
@Bean
public Traverson traverson( final OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate ) {
   try {
      final Traverson traverson = new Traverson( new URI( this.baseUrl ), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );
      traverson.setRestOperations( restTemplate );
      return traverson;
   }
   catch ( final URISyntaxException e ) {
      throw new BeanCreationException( e );
   }
}
```

When trying to use the `traverson` now, the template handles the OAuth2 dance pretty well, fetching a token and all - yet the header `Authorization: Bearer ...` unfortunately won't be sent by the `traverson`.

So when I call an endpoint now, e.g. `traverson.follow( "xyz" )...` the result is only the login form of the REST API provider :-(

My question:
Am I missing something or is my "OAuth2RestTemplate with Traverson" approach simply not supported or the `traverson` meant to be used in such a manner?

Any help appreciated! Currently I would say it simply isn't possible, yet most of the time in this "Spring world" there *are* ways to get it done - perhaps one of you knows how!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set HAL message converters predefined in Traverson.

```
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Traverson.getDefaultMessageConverters(mediaTypes));
```

In my case I've used an extension of Traverson to use the OAuth2 RestTemplate successfully.

```
public class ExtendedTraverson extends Traverson {

  public ExtendedTraverson(URI baseUri, RestTemplate restTemplate, List<MediaType> mediaTypes) {
    super(baseUri, mediaTypes);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getDefaultMessageConverters(mediaTypes));
    setRestOperations(restTemplate);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thx for your efforts, xvronny. Unfortunately we've canceled this `Traverson` endeavor for the moment, so I haven't had the opportunity to test your suggestion. I'll see to it as soon as I may and will afterwards accept your answer gladly :-)